# Why does "get_option" return an empty string instead of my default array?

Tags: php, wordpress

The below code results in the error: `Notice: Uninitialized string offset: 0`:

```
$defArray = array( "width" => "", "height" => "" );
$option = get_option( "myoption", $defArray );

//This throws the error
echo $option[ "width" ];

//This shows it as type "string"
var_dump( $option );
```

According to the docs, I should be able to pass a default value that gets returned if nothing is saved in that option (and nothing is, I just made it up). http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_option

Why is it not using the default value?

Answer (score 1):

Somehow in refreshing the page, the option got created. I am not sure how as I never submitted the form. Calling `delete_option(...)` stopped the error from occurring.

Answer (score 0):

you can force the return by parsing args;

```
$defArray = array( "width" => "", "height" => "" );
$option = get_option( "myoption", $defArray );
$option = wp_parse_args( $option , $defArray  );
```

Answer (score 0):

I know this is over 9 years old, but I've just spent the day debugging something similar. Our option got set to an empty string too, and was causing that to be returned instead of the default value.

The problem was that we'd used the `general` option group when registering the setting, and so any changes to the general settings i.e. saving changes on `wp-admin/options-general.php`, would cause our option to be set to the empty string.

The solution is to change the option group to `options` or some unique value to group your settings together.